# Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions for local administrator

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu, wsl-2

I have successfully installed WSL 2 and Ubuntu on my windows machine. If I start PowerShell and type bash it successfully starts bash.

However if I run PowerShell as Administrator and type bash I get the following message:

> Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
> Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
> https://aka.ms/wslstore

Worst part is that I'm pretty sure this worked yesterday(!)

Comment: You're probably right about it previously working.  It's working for me regardless of whether I start PowerShell through the Start Menu and a right-click "Run as administrator" or if I start PowerShell Core by running it through an elevated Windows Terminal.  What's your `$env:PATH` show when in the Administrator session?

Comment: Also, recommend moving this over to Super User, as this is really off-topic for Stack Overflow (not about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."*)

Comment: Well, the path's does differ somewhat, but... well I was going to say that none of them seems to have a path to the linux folder, or at least not to the place where to image is located, maybe it's installed somewhere else?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds did you experience the same thing?